# Help with 'xrandr' - High DPI w/ External

Tags: xrandr

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and am currently running 18.04 on the new Matebook X Pro.  The resolution is 3000x2000.  I have an external monitor with a resolution of 2560x1080.  However, connecting the monitor causes some insane scaling issues.  Everything on the external monitor is zoomed in to the point it's virtually unusable.

I've been Googling all morning and experimenting with various --fb, --scale, --pos, commands but have been unsuccessful.  I don't understand how to calculate the necessary resolutions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What?  That's not true at all.  You can alter the fb, position, panning, etc.  Setting the DPI didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the panning option of xrandr.

It has been well explained in Pandemum's answer in the following post:

[Change DPI on HiDPI laptop with two external monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628961/change-dpi-on-hidpi-laptop-with-two-external-monitors)